# Is there a WFS and WFS-T Java library that plays nicely with Android?

Tags: wfs, java, wfs-t

I have a GeoServer database and various programs that query it and so forth using GeoTools. Now I'm making a map app for Android, but not only is GeoTools quite large with all it's dependencies (15 mb after stripping out everything I don't need), but it doesn't like working with Android (first, it has an awful time failing to compile, but even if it did finish, I know that JDom, at least, doesn't work on Android).

Considering I only need WFS and WFS-T, is there any other Java library(ies) that I can use? Something more lightweight, hopefully.

EDIT: This is for adding a feature to an app I've already been working on for quite some time, which is why I'm looking for something this specific.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered writing a mobile web app using [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/)? It supports mobile phone browsers and WFS-T, and can play happily with GeoServer as a backend. The next version will support gestures and direct access to the phone's location services.

It does mean you'll have to use Javascript and HTML of course, but it would make your application easily portable to other handsets. I've created a simple map browser app for my Android phone with little problem, although I must confess I've only run the example WFS-T apps they provide.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a bit late for that. I'm not in the planning stage, but in the adding-extra-features stage. Starting again with a web app will mean discarding months of work. Unless this is something that can be integrated into an already existing app.

Comment: OGR (part of the GDAL library) supports WFS and WFS-T (http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_wfs.html) and there is an ongoing attempt to get it compiling using the Android NDK (Native Development Kit) http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingForAndroid I'm sure any help they receive would be most welcome.