# Android Apps to edit WFS-T

Tags: android, wfs-t

Are there any mobile Android Apps where you can edit the Features served via a WFS-T?

Comment: Please explain your question in detail. According to your question ArcGIS app for Android (and many more apps available in play store such as Geo-mobile or Locus free) has the capacity to edit the features.

Comment: I'm running a WFS on geoserver and would like to edit the features using an android device. I know that the ArcGIS App can handle WFS-T but I thought it's only possible to connect it to a ArcGIS Server, isn't it? How can you edit the features of a WFS with Locus?

Comment: Please check following link :https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:gdbofKdlpKkJ:www.hig.no/content/download/28790/329796/file/yaowapa.pdf+&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESh8QyGOqeGnbPkX54gwncB--zJvnQXqDMkImS-Ua7e1v1T3aCI_G2XW4JE-AIuotrKQxMjTAv4bIFbcLix0k7WfvhYXakcjcVrpRpkRNk9EdXhknfqp0ThPP0VmtzhFqCMVCXhj&sig=AHIEtbRn1K0D_0NWgbZoj9XvyWpIhV22Og

Comment: I apologizes Locus is used for different application and not suitable according to your requirement

Comment: Have you ruled out OpenLayers as suggested [**here**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9221/is-there-a-wfs-and-wfs-t-java-library-that-plays-nicely-with-android)?  Or are you looking for something that requires no development?

Comment: I was looking for something that doesn't require development